# Why does the infobox in my MSN Map not close?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, virtual-earth

I'm having a bit of trouble with this [map](http://bit.ly/hzdDHL), invoked by the "View our interactive map" button in the middle of the content area.

If you double click a point such as `8` which causes a zoom and then afterwards it causes the info box to appear, the hide logic is wrong.

If you try to close the `x`, it will fail. This is probably because the user clicked too fast and the map thinks its in zoom mode when infact it should be in info box mode.

Has anyone ran into this issue before? Looks like I have to mess around with `window.ero.hide` and some other functions.. because `map.HideInfoBox` doesn't hide the map.

**EDIT**: The script used is [here](http://www.drhmaui.com/js/jquery-map-new.js). I did not code it, but the relevant bit has:

```
onclick="EnableEroHide();map.HideInfoBox();changePin();return false;"
```

The `map.HideInfoBox()` should hide the info box.

Comment: Seems to work fine in Opera 11.

Comment: page won't load for me - please try to include code within the question rather than sending people off site.

Comment: @Hamish - I usually do in my questions, but due to time constraints I had to make a quick question. I'll try modifying sometime today if I don't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the hide function was being overridden by an empty `function(){return;}`. I had to save a reference to the hide function and invoke it manually.